# Keyboard with smile and more icons of the phone to be used by the user in EditText

Tags: android, keyboard

In an Android application,

I get data from the user through EditText

I need the user would be able to add smile and more icons and other possible shapes to the entered text too

The point is I'm not able to open a keyboard equipped with the smile icons so that the user selects one

I attach my keyboard and interested keyboard as following:

[image: my keyboard]

[image: Interested keyboard with smile selection possibility]

Answer (score 0):

try https://mashable.com/2014/06/18/emoji-on-android/ 
or you can also use google normal keyboard to add smile in edittext

Comment: How to call google normal keyboard or emojj in my application (do you have any code in this regard?)